# How to manage cookies with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, cookies

I'm setting two cookies in a page called reservation.php where i read the content of two input through $POST method,

```
if (isset($_POST['chambre']) && isset($_POST['option_chambre'])  )
{
setcookie('preference',$_POST['option_chambre'],time()+3600*24*31,"http://127.0.0.1/partie_3_f/accueil.php",null, false, true);
setcookie('type',$_POST['chambre'],time()+3600*24*31,"http://127.0.0.1/partie_3_f/accueil.php",null, false, true);       
}
```

Then in other page i'm trying to check the DB and show the results where the value of two colums will have the same value as the one stocked in the cookies

```
<?php 
{
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','pdxhotel');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$type=$_COOKIE['type'];
$pre = $_COOKIE['preference'];
$soal = $con->query("select * from chambre where vide = 1 and   type_chambre='".$type."' and preference = '".$pre."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($soal)==0)
{
    echo "pas de chambre disponible";
}
else
{ 
?>
<div id="titres" align="center">
<label >----------------------------</label>
<h2 id="tit"> Resultat de recherche </h2>
<label >----------------------------</label>
</div>
<?php 
for ($i = 0; $i<mysqli_num_rows($soal); $i++)
{
?>
    <div id="offre1" class="offre">
    <img src="Images/chambre3.jpg" width="100%" height="50%" />
    <p  > <?php echo "Chambre de type",$_COOKIE['type'],"and qui vérifie la condition:",$_COOKIE['preference']?> </p>
 </div>
<?php
}
}             
}   
?>
```

I'm having a problem  Notice: Array to string conversion ! 
It's my first time to work with cookies can you please tell me what's wrong and what should i do ?

Comment: Which line is that error happening on?

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. Please learn to use prepared queries with `bind_param`.

Comment: @Barmar the problem is happening in the select request

Comment: What do `var_dump($type)` and `var_dump($pre)` show?

Comment: as @barmar said, don't forget to check as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: array (size=1)
  '$id' => string 'a' (length=1)
array (size=1)
  '$id' => string '1' (length=1)

Comment: That sounds like your form has `name="chambre[id]"` rather than just `name="chambre"`. So `$_POST['chambre']` is an associative array, not a single string, and this array is being put into the cookie.

Comment: No i don't have any array as a name

Comment: @Barmar you cannot store an array in cookie without serialising it or assigning multiple cokies with cookiename[] format

Comment: I tried to convert the the type of the cookies the first one contain an interger the second one contain varchar so i put string $_cookie['type'] but it doesn't work while the first one worked

Comment: Can you pls post var_dump($_COOKIE) here as well?

Comment: string 'Array' (length=5) // the first cookie
int 1 // the second one

Comment: Sorry, should have asked for print_r(), not var_dump()!

Comment: Pls paste the full output into the question in a formatted way.

Comment: Also, pls paste $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']. You have sg in your cookies that make php think it is an array instead of string

Comment: @Shadow the Phrase Array111 is all what i get

Comment: Array111 PHPSESSID=vmejgnbc0ptq893eo7fei9sgc7; preference[$id]=1; type[$id]=a; preference=1; type=a

Comment: @Shadow I thought `setcookie()` might be serializing it automatically when the value isn't a string, but I just checked the documentation and it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']` are the key to this issue:

```
"PHPSESSID=vmejgnbc0ptq893eo7fei9sgc7; preference[$id]=1; type[$id]=a; preference=1; type=a"
```

- PHPSESSID: this is is your php session id, this is fine
- preference=1; type=a: these are the cookies set by your code in the OP because their the keys are set with plain text.
- preference[$id]=1; type[$id]=a: these keys cause the issue. First of all, these seem to be duplicate of preference and type, put the bigger issue is that they have a [$id] in their names. When php parses the cookie string into the $_COOKIE array, these values are interpreted as arrays themselves with $i as their key. When you try to read the preference and type keys as strings to insert their values into the sql query string, you get the "Notice: Array to string conversion" message.

Since we cannod debug your code, we cannot determine from where these duplicate and incorrect keys are coming from. My first guess is that these cookies are remnants of an earlier test. Try to remove them in the browser used for testing. If they reappear again, then you need to debug your code an establish where you set additional cookies.

My other suggestion would be to check if you could use session or get parameters in the url instead of cookies for passing these variables.